# What is the accepted way to contact the Ubuntu development team

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting

### Background

I use Ubuntu on a daily basis. I will get the occasional crash that warrants a developer report tool. It sends in the report. (I have no idea if this is useful. Often I know the cause and it was due to my own stupidity.)

More often then a crash I will get a process hang or just mangled graphics if I'm lucky. Really minor glitches are more common. A good number of my errors are found under high ram usage conditions i.e. 7 out of 8GB 5% Swap usage.... I understand this is reckless behavior but it should only slow my system down, not break it. Especially with only having 5% swap... (Not the issue)

## Question

Is there a good way that I can give Canonical more data so I can live better or am I doomed to stay stagnant.

I feel this is an appropriate question because:

- there should be a finite number of ways to contact developers
- there is no opinion in a list of options on how to better send data
- It's clear there are a lot of errors in 18.04LTS (I know it's only been a month)

There may be no answer to the question but I assume there's somewhere like GitHub or something where issues on components of the suite can be raised?

Comment: it sounds like you're asking *around* `ubuntu-bug`  (ie. wanting an alternative to the default method).  Once its finished its default bug-report, additional attachments can be added including useful description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

The page has topics and links that include:

- How to report bugs
- Determine if the bug is really a bug
- Perform a survey of your problem
- Reporting an application crash in the development release
- Reporting an application crash in the stable release

Once you report a bug (or feature request) it will be assigned a number and you'll have the ability to track it, as well as share the bug report link with others.